# Hadoop pig latin style guide?

Tags: hadoop, coding-style

I'm looking to take the short cut on formatting/style for pig latin (hadoop-ay).

Does anyone know where I can find a style guide?

Answer (score 2):

Here are some good examples: https://github.com/Ganglion/sounder

Comment: Thank you!  This is a great help!

Answer (score 1):

If finding a style guide doesn't yield one, then the next best bet would be to look for code that's already out there and see how programmers are using it already.

Sometimes there is no short cut.